# Fixtures not loading in Rails test console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginning to write tests for a new Rails 6 app and am trying to get fixtures loading. This is for the Users model and I wrote my own (auth from scratch) authentication. Here are the relevant files:

../test/fixtures/users.yml

```
one:
  email: MyString
  password_digest: "test"
  first_name: "John"
  last_name: "Smith"
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  has_secure_password

  #validations section
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

I can run `rails db:fixtures:load` with no errors, but when I load the console in the test environment I get:

```
 rails c -e test
Running via Spring preloader in process 15677
Loading test environment (Rails 6.1.3.1)
 :001 > User.all
   (0.5ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't add digests to your fixtures - you provide the cleartext password and let bcrypt encrypt the password for you. In general you never actually set or get a password digest - bcrypt/has_encypted_password does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture I had above was fine I just need to load the fixtures into the test database first with `rails db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test`